# Composition of Irreducible Representation and Non-surjective homomorphism: counterexample

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

I came across [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/741191/composition-of-irreducible-representation-and-surjective-homomorphism) where it proved that if $\phi: G\rightarrow H$ be a epimorphism and $\psi: H \rightarrow GL (V)$ is an irreducible representation, then $\psi \circ \phi$ is an irreducible representation of . I learned from elsewhere that this statement is actually "if and only if", and so I was trying to find a counterexample to this problem where $\phi$ is not surjective, but I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $G$ to be the trivial group and $H$ a non-Abelian finite group. There
is a unique homomorphism $\phi:G\to H$. But $H$ has an irreducible representation
$\psi$ of degree $d\ge2$. Then $\psi\circ\phi$ also has degree $d$ but the
only irreducible representation of the trivial group is the trivial representation
of degree one.